# python manually finish writing file

Tags: python, file, sockets, exit

I have a program which receive a file.BIN from socket TCP/IP but I don't know how to exit the writing loop

Here is a piece of my code:

```
    with open(f"recv_{FILENAME}", "wb") as f:
        while True:
            data = client_tcp.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                f.write(data)
                print("Data receiving")
                if 
                #I want to go out the loop here if the file is completely received                
        print("File Received")
```

Hope to get help from everybody.
**Many thanks**

Comment: Your code already does that. `not data` is when the file is completely received. Did you write the server yourself too?

Comment: @user253751 , yes i wrote the server also. But I don't know why I can't not exit the loop even I tried with the simulation server (which is written by myself) and an FPGA which has install a server TCP IP also.

Comment: How does the server tell the client that the file is completely received?

Comment: @user253751 this is "if not data" happened.

Comment: so you have "if not data: break". What does break do? It makes it go out of the loop. So it seems like you have already solved your own problem?

Comment: No, it did not make exit the loop. So I don't understand where i was wrong here :(

Comment: So how does the server tell the client the file is completely received?